# ASP.NET MVC - Posting a form with custom fields of different data types

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

In my ASP.NET MVC 2 web application, I allow users to create custom input fields of different data types to extend our basic input form. While tricky, building the input form from a collection of custom fields is straight-forward enough.

However, I'm now to the point where I want to handle the posting of this form and I'm not certain what the best way to handle this would be. Normally, we'd use strongly-typed input models that get bound from the various statically-typed inputs available on the form. However, I'm at a loss for how to do this with a variable number of input fields that represent different data types.

**A representative input form might look something like:**

- My date field: [ date time input
  control ]
- My text field: [ text input
  field ]
- My file field: [ file upload
  control ]
- My number field: [ numerical input control ]
- My text field 2: [text input field ]
- etc...

**Ideas I've thought about are:**

- Sending everything as strings (except for the file inputs, which would need to be handled specially).
- Using a model with an "object" property and attempting to bind to that (if this is even possible).
- Sending a json request to my controller with the data encoded properly and attempting to parse that.
- Manually processing the form collection in my controller post action - certainly an option, but I'd love to avoid this.

Has anyone tackled an issue like this before? If so, how did you solve it?

**Update:**

My "base" form is handled on another input area all together, so a solution doesn't need to account for any sort of inheritence magic for this. I'm just interested in handling the custom fields on this interface, not my "base" ones.

**Update 2:**

Thank you to ARM and smartcaveman; both of you provided good guidance for how this could be done. I will update this question with my final solution once its been implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would begin to approach the issue.  A custom model binder would be pretty easy to build based on the FormKey property (which could be determined by the index and/or label, depending).

```
public class CustomFormModel
{
    public string FormId { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public CustomFieldModel[] Fields { get; set; }
}
public class CustomFieldModel
{
    public DataType DateType { get; set; } //  System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
    public string FormKey { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
public class CustomFieldModel<T> : CustomFieldModel
{
    public new T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Also, I noticed one of the comments below had a filtered model binder system.  Jimmy Bogard from Automapper made a really helpful post about this method at http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/03/17/a-better-model-binder.aspx , and later revised in, http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/11/19/a-better-model-binder-addendum.aspx .  It has been very helpful for me in building custom model binders.

**Update**

I realized that I misinterpreted the question, and that he was specifically asking how to handle posting of the form "with a variable number of input fields that represent different data types".  I think the best way to do this is to use a structure similar to above but leverage the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).  Basically, you will need to create an interface like `IFormComponent` and implement it for each datatype that would be represented.  I wrote and commented an example interface to help explain how this would be accomplished:

```
public interface IFormComponent
{
    //  the id on the html form field.  In the case of a composite Id, that doesn't have a corresponding 
    //  field you should still use something consistent, since it will be helpful for model binding
    //  (For example, a CompositeDateField appearing as the third field in the form should have an id 
    //  something like "frmId_3_date" and its child fields would be "frmId_3_date_day", "frmId_3_date_month",
    //  and "frmId_3_date_year".
    string FieldId { get; }

    //  the human readable field label
    string Label { get; }

    //  some functionality may require knowledge of the 
    //  Parent component.  For example, a DayField with a value of "30"
    //  would need to ask its Parent, a CompositeDateField
    //  for its MonthField's value in order to validate
    //  that the month is not "February"
    IFormComponent Parent { get; }

    //  Gets any child components or null if the 
    //  component is a leaf component (has no children).
    IList<IFormComponent> GetChildren();

    //  For leaf components, this method should accept the AttemptedValue from the value provider
    //  during Model Binding, and create the appropriate value.  
    //  For composites, the input should be delimited in someway, and this method should parse the 
    //  string to create the child components.  
    void BindTo(string value);

    //  This method should parse the Children or Underlying value to the 
    //  default used by your business models.  (e.g. a CompositeDateField would 
    //  return a DateTime.  You can get type safety by creating a FormComponent<TValue>
    //  which would help to avoid issues in binding.
    object GetValue();

    //  This method would render the field to the http response stream.
    //  This makes it easy to render the forms simply by looping through 
    //  the array.  Implementations could extend this for using an injected 
    //  formatting 
    void Render(TextWriter writer);
}
```

I am assuming that the custom forms can be accessed via some sort of id which can be contained as a form parameter.  With that assumption, the model binder and provider could look something like this.

```
public interface IForm : IFormComponent
{
    Guid FormId { get; }
    void Add(IFormComponent component);
}
public interface IFormRepository
{
    IForm GetForm(Guid id);
}
public class CustomFormModelBinder : IModelBinder   
{
    private readonly IFormRepository _repository;
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult result;
        if(bindingContext.ValueProvider.TryGetValue("_customFormId", out result))
        {
            var form = _repository.GetForm(new Guid(result.AttemptedValue));
            var fields = form.GetChildren();
            //  loop through the fields and bind their values 
            return form;
        }
        throw new Exception("Form ID not found.");
    }
}
```

Obviously, all the code here is just to get the point across, and would need to be completed and cleaned up for actual use.  Also, even if completed this would only bind to an implementation of the IForm interface, not a strongly typed business object.  (It wouldn't be a huge step to convert it to a dictionary and build a strongly typed proxy using the Castle DictionaryAdapter, but since your users are dynamically creating the forms on the site, there is probably no strongly typed model in your solution and this is irrelevant).  Hope this helps more.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, very insightful.

Answer (score 1):

Take a peek at what I did here: [MVC2 Action to handle multiple models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603211/mvc2-action-to-handle-multiple-models/3604064#3604064) and see if can get you on the right track.

If you use a FormCollection as one of your parameters to your action, you can then go thru that form collection looking for bits of data here or there in order to bind those values to whatever an then save the data.  You are most likely going to need to take advantage of both strategy and command patterns to get this to work.

Best of luck, feel free to ask follow-up questions.

Edit:

Your method which does the work should look something like this:

```
private/public void SaveCustomFields(var formId, FormCollection collection) //var as I don't know what type you are using to Id the form.
{
    var binders = this.binders.select(b => b.CanHandle(collection)); //I used IOC to get my list of IBinder objects
    // Method 1:    
    binders.ForEach(b => b.Save(formId, collection)); //This is the execution implementation.
    // Method 2:
    var commands = binders.Select(b => b.Command(formId, collection));
    commands.ForEach(c => c.Execute());    
}

public DateBinder : IBinder //Example binder
{
    public bool CanHandle(FormCollection collection)
    {
        return (null != collection["MyDateField"]); //Whatever the name of this field is.
    }

    //Method 1
    public void Save(var formId, FormCollection collection)
    {
        var value = DateTime.Parse(collection["MyDateField"]);
        this.someLogic.Save(formId, value); //Save the value with the formId, or however you wish to save it.
    }
    //Method 2
    public Command Command(var formId, FormCollection collection)
    {
        //I haven't done command pattern before so I'm not sure exactly what to do here.
        //Sorry that I can't help further than that.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this info, your approach looks very interesting. I'll probably have some follow-ups for you on Monday.

Comment: ARM; I'd be happy to award you the bounty if you'd be willing to post/share more relevant implementation details.

Comment: The most important part of this is IUIWrapper.CanHandle (you'll want to use a Select rather than SingleOrDefault to get multiple wrappers).  The CanHandle method takes a FormCollection and attempts to grab a collection element (var X = collection["SomeValue"]; return X != null;) which will determine if particular form collection element exists.

Once you have your collection of wrappers, each wrapper will have a command to save that particular element to your repository and then simply run thru the collection of commands to store the data to your repository.

Again, feel free to ask follow-up.

Comment: @ARM: thanks for updating your post; I'm thinking in my scenario that I'd have to rely on more than one logical form entry in the collection per field. Most importantly, I'd need to know the id and datatype of my custom field and based on the datatype, try to cast the third entry of interest to the appropriate type.

Comment: As long as you know what the form name and type will be, you can create a binder for that form name.  Otherwise, you could create a few hidden form values ("MyNumberField" with "MyNumberField_id" and "MyNumberField_type") and then use those to do the binding.  They would all come in as strings, however, and how to convert the string "int" into class int and then bind "MyNumberField" to that class is a problem I've thankfully not had to solve.

Comment: @ARM: Yes, my situation is somewhat more complicated, but I think having corresponding "meta data" hidden fields that reveal the type and id of the custom inputs is a decent way to solve this. I'm waiting for others to weigh in here, but your approach seems like a good starting point for me.

Comment: It's probably not good to execute the Save from the ModelBinder.  It seems like that its pretty obviously the responsibility of the Controller (and maybe ActionFilters).  However, if the Action Method of the Controller takes a Command as a model parameter, it makes sense to create the Command model in the binder.

Answer (score 0):

I would think one of the best options is to create a custom model binder, which makes it possible to have custom logic behind the scenes and still very customizable code behind.

Maybe these articles can help you:

http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/03/templated-helpers-and-custom-model-binders-in-asp-net-mvc-2/

http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Model_Binders_in_ASPNET_MVC.aspx

More specifically I would probably take as the controller argument a custom class with all "base" properties included. The class could then for example include a dictionary linking the name of each field to either just an object or an interface which you implement once for each data-type making it simple to process the data later.

/Victor